# How to pass dynamic value to other widget using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create condition that if first api didn't finish load when click on bottom navigation tab it will not navigate to other tab. So I want to pass boolean that will change to true when api is loaded, the problem is I don't know how to pass this dynamic value to my custom Bottom Navigation Bar. Is there an other way instead of using global variable?

This is my code.

landingPage.dart

```
// This global variable is change to true when receive callback from api
bool isComplete = false;

class _NavigationItem {
  _NavigationItem(this.iconFile, this.caption, this.page);

  final String iconFile;
  final String caption;
  final Widget page;
}

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  LandingPage({Key key, this.username}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<_NavigationItem> _navItems = [];
  double _bottomNavBarHeight = 46;
  double _iconSize = 26;
  double _circleSize = 52;
  int _animationDuration = 300;
  double _circleStrokeWidth = 0;

  BottomNavigationController _navigationController;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Context of a state is available to us from the moment the State loads its dependencies
    // Since we need context object so it need to be accessed inside this overridden method.
    _navItems = [
      _NavigationItem(
          "assets/icons/home.svg",
          S.of(context).landing_nav_home,
          HomePage(
            username: widget.username,
            callback: (value) { isComplete = value; }, // receiving callback data
          )),
      _NavigationItem("assets/icons/friend.svg",
          S.of(context).landing_nav_friend, FriendPage()),
      _NavigationItem(
          "assets/icons/chat.svg", S.of(context).landing_nav_chat, ChatPage()),
      _NavigationItem("assets/icons/widget.svg",
          S.of(context).landing_nav_widget, WidgetPage()),
      _NavigationItem("assets/icons/more.svg",
          S.of(context).landing_nav_setting, SettingPage()),
    ];

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigationController = new BottomNavigationController(_selectedIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90),
              child: _navItems.elementAt(_selectedIndex).page,
            ),
            _createBottomNavigationBar()
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  void _onNavigationBarItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget _createBottomNavigationBar() {
    return Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: _bottomNav());
  }

  Widget _bottomNav() {
    List<TabItem> tabItems = List.of([
      new TabItem(Icons.home_outlined, "", CommonColor.accent,
          asset: "assets/icons/home.svg"),
      new TabItem(Icons.person, "", CommonColor.accent,
          asset: "assets/icons/friends.svg"),
      new TabItem(Icons.chat_bubble_outline, "", CommonColor.accent),
      new TabItem(Icons.widgets_outlined, "", CommonColor.accent),
      new TabItem(Icons.more_horiz, "", CommonColor.accent),
    ]);
    return BottomNavigation(
      tabItems,
      controller: _navigationController,
      barHeight: _bottomNavBarHeight,
      iconsSize: _iconSize,
      circleSize: _circleSize,
      selectedIconColor: Colors.white,
      normalIconColor: CommonColor.accent,
      circleStrokeWidth: _circleStrokeWidth,
      barBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: _animationDuration),
      selectedCallback: (int selectedPos) {
        print("selected: $_selectedIndex");
        _onNavigationBarItemTapped(selectedPos);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _navigationController.dispose();
  }
}
```

BottomNavigation.dart

```
typedef BottomNavSelectedCallback = Function(int selectedPos);

class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<TabItem> tabItems;
  final int selectedPos;
  final double barHeight;
  final double padding;
  final Color barBackgroundColor;
  final double circleSize;
  final double circleStrokeWidth;
  final double iconsSize;
  final Color selectedIconColor;
  final Color normalIconColor;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final BottomNavSelectedCallback selectedCallback;
  final BottomNavigationController controller;

  BottomNavigation(this.tabItems,
      {this.selectedPos = 0,
      this.barHeight = 60,
      this.barBackgroundColor = Colors.white,
      this.circleSize = 58,
      this.circleStrokeWidth = 4,
      this.iconsSize = 32,
      this.padding = 16,
      this.selectedIconColor = Colors.white,
      this.normalIconColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      this.selectedCallback,
      this.controller})
      : assert(tabItems != null && tabItems.length >= 2 && tabItems.length <= 5,
            "tabItems is required");

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
}

class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Curve _animationsCurve = Cubic(0.27, 1.21, .77, 1.09);

  AnimationController itemsController;
  Animation<double> selectedPosAnimation;
  Animation<double> itemsAnimation;

  List<double> _itemsSelectedState;

  int selectedPos;
  int previousSelectedPos;

  BottomNavigationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.controller != null) {
      _controller = widget.controller;
      previousSelectedPos = selectedPos = _controller.value;
    } else {
      previousSelectedPos = selectedPos = widget.selectedPos;
      _controller = BottomNavigationController(selectedPos);
    }

    _controller.addListener(_newSelectedPosNotify);

    _itemsSelectedState = List.generate(widget.tabItems.length, (index) {
      return selectedPos == index ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    });

    itemsController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: widget.animationDuration);
    itemsController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _itemsSelectedState.asMap().forEach((i, value) {
          if (i == previousSelectedPos) {
            _itemsSelectedState[previousSelectedPos] =
                1.0 - itemsAnimation.value;
          } else if (i == selectedPos) {
            _itemsSelectedState[selectedPos] = itemsAnimation.value;
          } else {
            _itemsSelectedState[i] = 0.0;
          }
        });
      });
    });

    selectedPosAnimation = makeSelectedPosAnimation(
        selectedPos.toDouble(), selectedPos.toDouble());

    itemsAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: itemsController, curve: _animationsCurve));
  }

  Animation<double> makeSelectedPosAnimation(double begin, double end) {
    return Tween(begin: begin, end: end).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: itemsController, curve: _animationsCurve));
  }

  void onSelectedPosAnimate() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _newSelectedPosNotify() {
    _setSelectedPos(widget.controller.value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double fullHeight =
        widget.barHeight + (widget.circleSize / 2) + widget.circleStrokeWidth;
    double sectionsWidth = (fullWidth / 1.2) / widget.tabItems.length;

    //Create the boxes Rect
    List<Rect> boxes = List();
    widget.tabItems.asMap().forEach((i, tabItem) {
      double left = (i + 0.5) * sectionsWidth;
      double top = fullHeight - widget.barHeight;
      double right = left + sectionsWidth;
      double bottom = fullHeight;
      boxes.add(Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom));
    });

    List<Widget> children = List();

    // This is the full view transparent background (have free space for circle)
    children.add(Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: widget.padding),
        child: Container(
          width: fullWidth,
          height: fullHeight,
        )));

    // This is the bar background (bottom section of our view)
    children.add(Positioned.fill(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: widget.padding,
            right: widget.padding,
            bottom: widget.padding),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: widget.barHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: widget.barBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              boxShadow: [
                new BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 8.0)
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      top: fullHeight - widget.barHeight,
    ));

    // This is the circle handle on selected
    children.add(new Positioned(
      child: Container(
        width: widget.circleSize,
        height: widget.circleSize,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14)),
                  color: widget.barBackgroundColor),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(widget.circleStrokeWidth),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14)),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        CommonColor.primary,
                        widget.tabItems[selectedPos].circleColor,
                        CommonColor.slipBg,
                      ])),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      left: boxes[selectedPos].center.dx - (widget.circleSize / 2),
      top: 0,
    ));

    //Here are the Icons and texts of items
    boxes.asMap().forEach((int pos, Rect r) {
      // Icon
      Color iconColor = pos == selectedPos
          ? widget.selectedIconColor
          : widget.normalIconColor;
      double scaleFactor = pos == selectedPos ? 1.2 : 1.0;
      children.add(
        Positioned(
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: scaleFactor,
            child: widget.tabItems[pos].asset != null
                ? SvgPicture.asset(widget.tabItems[pos].asset,
                    color: iconColor,
                    width: widget.iconsSize,
                    height: widget.iconsSize,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)
                : Icon(
                    widget.tabItems[pos].icon,
                    size: widget.iconsSize,
                    color: iconColor,
                  ),
          ),
          left: r.center.dx - (widget.iconsSize / 2),
          top: r.center.dy -
              (widget.iconsSize / 2) -
              (_itemsSelectedState[pos] *
                  ((widget.barHeight / 2) + widget.circleStrokeWidth)),
        ),
      );

      if (pos != selectedPos) {
        children.add(Positioned.fromRect(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _controller.value = pos;
            },
          ),
          rect: r,
        ));
      }
    });

    return Stack(
      children: children,
    );
  }

  void _setSelectedPos(int pos) {
    previousSelectedPos = selectedPos;
    selectedPos = pos;

    itemsController.forward(from: 0.0);

    selectedPosAnimation = makeSelectedPosAnimation(
        previousSelectedPos.toDouble(), selectedPos.toDouble());
    selectedPosAnimation.addListener(onSelectedPosAnimate);

    if (widget.selectedCallback != null) {
      widget.selectedCallback(selectedPos);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    itemsController.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_newSelectedPosNotify);
  }
}

class BottomNavigationController extends ValueNotifier<int> {
  BottomNavigationController(int value) : super(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FutureBuilder/ StreamBuilder to listen to an event after your api call is finished. Something like this:

```dart
Future<dynamic> yourApiCall() async {
  // Execute your functions
  return someValue;
}
```

Here in the UI, you can listen to the output of this function with:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: yourApiCall(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return BottomNavigation(
        tabItems,

        // ...other properties

        selectedCallback: (int selectedPos) {
          print("selected: $_selectedIndex");
          if (snapshot.hasData) // Here you check if the snapshot.data is different from null. That means your api has finished and returned some value
            _onNavigationBarItemTapped(selectedPos); // Only then, you notify the callback function
        },
      );
    });
```